# Border of control flickers in windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, controls, border, flicker

In my custom control file:

```
namespace myApp {
    public partial class MyStatusBar : Label {

      public MyStatusBar () {
          InitializeComponent ();
          this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
          this.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
      }

      protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs pe) {
          base.OnPaint (pe);
          pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle (new Pen (Color.Azure), ClientRectangle);         
      }
    }
}
```

In my form:

```
MyStatusBar mStatusBarLabel = new MyStatusBar ();

public MCADDrg() {
     InitializeComponent ();

     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, false);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
     this.SetStyle (ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

     splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add (mStatusBarLabel);   
     splitContainer1.Panel2.MouseMove += Panel2_MouseMove;
}

void Panel2_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if( splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
        mStatusBarLabel.Text = "X = " + e.X + " Y = " + e.Y;
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I get rid of this? I tried some other posts answer. But didn't work for me. Assume that (in fact) I'm a newbie.

Comment: The basic solution to "my control flickers" is to double-buffer the rendering. There are many existing questions and answers on Stack Overflow on the topic already, including the marked one. If you find yourself with a _specific_ question involving implementation of double-buffered rendering, and which is not already answered (which you've determined by performing a thorough search on the site), please post a new question, including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing clearly what you've tried, explaining what specific problem you have.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I should have included the things tried from other posts question. This 'Double buffer' didn't solve my issue.

Comment: protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    return cp;
  }
} 
This code in form helped me. :)